# How to know if a zip lock bag is safe for sous-vide (or boiling), without indication from the manufacturer?

Tags: food-safety, equipment, temperature, sous-vide

The only zip lock bags available in local stores for me are labelled that they are supposed to be used for refrigerating food.

Is it possible to know whether those bags are safe to put in water temps near or at boiling temperature or not ?

Is there some sort of experiment or indication that would suggest that the bags are BPA-free and EA-free ?

Can we assume that bags that are made for food, are supposed to be safe regardless of the temperature ? (up to 100c only though)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the brand you use but, as many of us do, refer generically to ziplock bags. For the brand name product, SC Johnson, which makes both Ziploc® brand bags and Saran ™ Wrap, states that it does not use BPA in these products.

> [SC Johnson’s Ziploc® brand Bags and Containers are BPA free](https://ziploc.com/en/sustainability-and-safety). Our products are extensively evaluated for toxicity and safety and comply with applicable quality and safety regulations.

If you brand you use doesn't make a similar statement on the box or the manufacturer's web site, then better to use Ziploc, not an off brand.

[Modern Cuisine](http://modernistcuisine.com/2013/03/is-it-safe-cook-plastic/) noted that:

> [T]he safest plastics for use with food are high-density polyethylene, low-density polyethylene, and polypropylene. Virtually all sous vide bags are made from these plastics, as are most brand-name food storage bags and plastic wraps such as Saran Wrap.